# On Hyperfinite ness

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $M\subset B(\mathcal{H})$ is hyperfinite type $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor, does it imply $PM$ is again hyperfinite type $\mathrm{II}_1$, where $P$ is a projection in $M'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known (see, for instance, Proposition 5.5.5 in Kadison Ringrose) that $MP\simeq MC_P$, where $C_P$ is the central carrier of $P$. As $C_P\in Z(M')=Z(M)=\mathbb C I$, we have $C_P=I$ and so $PM\simeq M$ via the explicit isomorphism $Pm\longmapsto m $.

Comment: what will be the hypertrace in $PM$?

Comment: There's no "the" hypertrace. I assume you are talking about the trace?  Since the trace in a factor is unique, if $\tau $ is the trace of $M $ then the trace on $PM $ is $\tau'(Pm)=\tau (m) $.

Comment: But is $\tau'$ well defined?

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: After chopping by whatever projection is, the induced vN algebra remains type II_1

Comment: I don't follow.

Comment: @ Martin, I mean if $M$ is $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor, by your argument $PM$ is type $\mathrm{II}_1$, where $P$ is a projections in $M'$.  I don't understand why the dimension $\mathcal{H}$ over $M$ does not have a role.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I still don't follow. It's isomorphic to $M$, so it is obviously a II$_1$-factor.

Comment: Well, if $M$ is not a factor, still can I say it is finite vN algebra.

Comment: Sorry, you have me completely lost. In your question $M$ was the hyperfinite II$_1$-factor.

Comment: Yes. I am asking it more generally.

Comment: If $M$ is a finite von Neumann algebra, then $MC_P$ is finite and then so is $PM$. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Hi, Martin, with respect to the trace $\tau'$, what is the cyclic and separating vector?

Comment: No idea. $\ \ \ $

Comment: But with respect to $\tau'$ GNS of PM will be $P\mathcal{H}$ for sure.

Comment: Yes, in this situation the map $m\longmapsto Pm$ is isometric at the Hilbert space level, too.